# CodeMirror show 2 scroll

Tags: javascript, css, right-to-left, codemirror

I want to use `CodeMirror` in my project. It's load but editor show 2 scroll, one in right by `CodeMirror` and one in left by css `overflow-y: scroll`. Is this problem because page direction or something else?
How Can I fix this problem or disable one of Scrolls?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution! The problem because of page direction. I fix the problem with change `CodeMirror` css and replace `right:0` with `left:0` in `.CodeMirror-scrollbar` css class.